# How to set craco config to handle `transformIgnorePatterns` for testing?

Tags: babeljs, create-react-app, ts-jest, babel-jest, craco

For running the tests in a project that is using Create React App 5 I need to set the `transformIgnorePatterns` property for some dependencies that weren't transpiled.

I can do it from the command line as follows:

```
npm run test -- --transformIgnorePatterns "node_modules/(?!(swiper|ssr-window|dom7)/)"
```

and I can do it after ejecting by setting the `jest` property in `package.json` as follows:

```
{
  ...
  transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(swiper|ssr-window|dom7/)\\.(js|jsx|mjs|cjs|ts|tsx)$",
    "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
  ],
  ...
}
```

I've been trying to do the same with `craco7.0.0-alpha.8` (needed to support versions 5 and above of CRA) by setting various combinations of the babel and jest properties in `craco.config.js`, but it doesn't seem that they're working at all *(I keep seeing the `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` error to solve which I needed the new setting)*.

```
module.exports = {
  babel: {
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/(?!(swiper|ssr-window|dom7))"
    ],
  },
  jest: {
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(swiper|ssr-window|dom7/)",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ]
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to set the `transformIgnorePatterns` property in craco config so that the necessary libraries will get compiled properly when running the tests?

Comment: not a solution, but we were just a dozen commits in so I switched to vite (since it seemed the only way to do it with cra was to eject the app...)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://craco.js.org/docs/configuration/jest/), standard jest configurations live under `jest.configure`. So your configuration should look something like this

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  jest: {
    configure: {
      transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!(swiper|ssr-window|dom7/)",
        "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

(I can verify that this works for the `resetMocks` property, but I've not tested `transformIgnorePatterns`).